# How to mount meter base to cedar siding on old house

Tags: electrical, meter

I'm in the process of rewiring my small 1910 home. The utility company has requested I move my meter to the front of the house. I plan on mounting my service panel on the inside of the house, directly behind the meter and connecting the two via a few inches of 2" schedule 80 PVC.

What's the best way to mount the meter base to the exterior of the house? Should I just screw it directly into the siding? Should I cut a rectangle out of the siding that is slightly larger than the meter and attach a plywood or PVC mounting block?

The house is old and has no sheathing under the siding (there appears to be horizontal shiplap under the siding with gaps between the boards). I'm in the rainy NW so waterproofing is a big concern. Below is a photo of the siding. It's not the meter's location but it gives an idea of what the house looks like.

Thanks!

[image: house siding]

Comment: How about using a few inches of rigid?  Requires a trip to the hardware store for cut-n-thread, but Far more fireproof than PVC...

Comment: Not a bad idea! I have to pick up some rigid for the mast going up through the roof so I might as well get a short span for the panel as well.

Comment: What is the material of the siding? How much overlap of the courses? The gaps may actually allow the walls to breathe and this may prevent mold and rot. It would of course allow entry for insects into the wall.

Comment: The siding is grooved cedar and I'm unsure of the overlap, I'd guess an inch or two. The gaps in the faux sheathing definitely let a little air (and moisture) into the wall cavities and I'm worried that if I cut a big square out of the siding for the meter I'll be letting in a whole lot more moisture...

Comment: Does your meter base have to be mounted to the home, or is a free standing base allowed?

Comment: It has to be mounted to the home unfortunately